# OSX Cocoa NSButton type checkbox " Select all " issue, and how to solve it?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have multiple checkboxes in a table view. And out of table, I have one checkbox with action select all that looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)selectAll:(NSButton *)sender {

    for (int i = 0; i < [mainTable numberOfRows]; i++) {

        NSTableCellView *cellView = [mainTable makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MainCell" owner:self];

        for(NSButton *button in cellView.subviews){

            //I have multiple buttons, i need one with toolTip
            if([[button toolTip] isEqualToString:@"select"]){

                [button setState:sender.state];

            }
        }           
    }

}
```

That code works great but VIEW IS NOT UPDATED.
I tried `[mainTable reloadData]` but my guess that is not for that.

Simple question how to update view?

I tried:

1) Creating new NSButton and replacing old one but no luck there. View was not updated.

2) Trying to create NSButtons dynamically instead of using Designer and then applying code, no luck there.
This was strange also. When I created dynamically elements in cellView only subviews was ones that i created with designer.

3) `[button setNeedsDisplay:YES]` also does not work;

I am not experienced Mac programmer.

**UPDATE**

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{

    NSDictionary *flag = [emails objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];

    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"MainCell"]){
        NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MainCell" owner:self];
        [cellView.textField setStringValue:flag[@"subject"]];
        cellView.textField.drawsBackground = YES;
        [cellView.textField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
        //[cellView setBackgroundStyle:NO];


        NSButton *checkBox;
        NSRect frame_checkbox = NSMakeRect(7, 35 , 317, 20);
        checkBox = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame_checkbox];
        //NSLog(@"Message id: %@", flag[@"id"]);
        [checkBox setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
        [checkBox setObjectValue:flag[@"id"]];
        [checkBox setState:NO];
        [checkBox setTitle:@""];
        [checkBox setToolTip:@"Select message with Id"];
```

I got this finally :

```
         if([flag[@"ischecked"] boolValue] == 1){ 
             [checkBox setState:YES]; 
         } 
         else{ 
           [checkBox setState:NO]; 
         } 
        [cellView addSubview:checkBox];

        //other subview shere


        return cellView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

this part of code is for adding subviews.

**NEW UPDATE**

```
NSMutableArray *emails;
emails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    [emails addObject:@{@"id":@"1", @"from":@"some name",
     @"subject":@"some subject",
     @"email":@"some email", 
     @"date":@"10 min ago", 
     @"ischecked":@NO}];
```

Since this is NSMutableArray I do not have addObject.
In order to do addObject this: `NSMutableArray *emails` has to be `NSMutableDictionary *emails`
but I have no idea how to addObject to NSMutableDictionary;

If I do something like:

```
for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in emails){
   NSLog(@"%@", dict);
   [dict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"ischecked"];

}
```

I am getting error:

```
[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: This violating the concept of MVC, you want to update your data model so that when you reload the datasource, your table knows how to display the proper state of the checkboxes.

Comment: @meda would you care to explain some more? You are saying that I use setNeedsDesplay:YES only on data reload?

Comment: no I am saying that you should not rely on cells because they can be reused, what you should do is update the datasource so that in your table you have logic to check the boxes or not once reloaded

Comment: @meda i understand what you are saying. So there is no way that I can update NSButton state programmatically with this cell approach ?

Comment: Yes my suggestion is programmatic, its like you set all checkbox on your datasource to yes, then inside of the tableDelegate you check them based on the boolean value

Comment: is it a checkbox per cell, or one cell has many subviews ?

Comment: @meda thank you. I will sure try to do that. I found similar approach somewhere. Anyway, will get back to you with new results :)

Comment: @meda one cell has many subviews.

Comment: Yes if you show me more code maybe i can help you achieve this

Comment: @meda look at update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `emails` is your data source:

`NSDictionary *flag = [emails objectAtIndex:row];`

`flag` is your dictionary at the indexPath.

You need to modify emails so that it holds the value for the checkbox then inside of `viewForTableColumn`  you do:

```
[checkbox setState:flag[@"ischecked"] ? NSOffState : NSOnState];
```

and to check them all:

```
- (IBAction)selectAll:(NSButton *)sender {
    NSMutableArray *emailCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(NSDictionary *dict in emails){
       NSLog(@"dict = %@", dict);
       NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
       [newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:dict];
       [newDict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"ischecked"];
       [emailCopy addObject:newDict];
       NSLog(@"newDict = %@", newDict);
    }

    emails = emailCopy;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I gave you the code for that `[checkbox setState:flag[@"ischecked"] ? NSOffState : NSOnState];` log flag to see your updated data

Comment: did you mean: [checkBox setState:flag[@"ischecked"] ? NSOffState : NSOnState];
        [cellView addSubview:checkBox];

Comment: You have not used a bool like in my example, since you have a string you need to compare to `1`

Comment: `bool isChecked = [flag[@"ischecked"] isEqualToString:@"1"];` then u can do `[checkBox setState:ischecked ? NSOffState : NSOnState];`

Comment: I refactor code and add @"ischecked":@NO to every email object and then [newDict setObject:@YES forKey:@"ischecked"];

Comment: I got this finally : if([flag[@"ischecked"] boolValue] == 1){
            
            [checkBox setState:YES];
            
        }
        else{
            
            [checkBox setState:NO];
            
        }

Comment: now i am facing other issue. subviews get regenerated and duplicated on reloadData, do you have maybe some experience with this.

Comment: You should subclass the `NSTableViewCell` instead of adding subview, this is an issue especially if you reload because you are reusing the cells

Comment: what do you mean by subclass NSTableViewCell? checkbox works.

Comment: @Johnny see here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TableView/TableViewOverview/TableViewOverview.html

Comment: You can subclass NSTableCellView to add additional subviews and behaviors, and you can use Interface Builder to modify a cell’s design and layout. Whether you use the standard NSTableCellView class or a custom subclass, an app retrieves a cell view at runtime and populates it with data, either programmatically or using Cocoa bindings. Because tables reuse cell views when possible, cell views can be varied and complex without negatively impacting memory usage.

Comment: @Johnny are you familiar with ios

Comment: yes I am. for NSTableCellView i have NSTableCellView.textFiled and NSTableCellView.imageView or something. I know what you are going to say for UICellView

Comment: In xcode add a new class, and inherit from `NSTableViewCell` then add properties to it. then you would like to the custom cell

Comment: check this link http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/how-to-create-simple-tableview-with-custom-cells

Comment: I was able to add custom cell from nib file. I designed nib file and then add labels, checkboxes etc. Now I can see all of that but data is not shown (view is not updated). I am accessing and setting values with this:  CustomCell *cell = [CustomCell new];
        [cell.select setState:NO];
        [cell.subject setStringValue:flag[@"from"]];
        [cell.name setStringValue:flag[@"from"]];
        [cell.arrivedAt setStringValue:flag[@"date"]];
        [cell.email setStringValue:flag[@"email"]];

Comment: Dont do `[CustomCell new]` ! do `CustomCell *cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomMainCell" owner:self];`

Comment: heheheh, this is great. I can design what ever I want in this cell. Everything works like a charm. I do not know how to thank you. I do not have code repetition and things .... just clean fro line code.

Comment: yes everytime you have a cell beyond the basic, you better of customizing it. Im glad I helped ;)

Comment: @Johnny nice interface, oh and how is Yosemite ? I have not upgraded yet !very tempting

Comment: I added you on skype ad on gtalk.

Comment: Yes this is Yosemite. I am having problem with Dock. When Xocde is opened Dock get stack sometimes.

Comment: I am having problem with reloadData. First row (of many) got selected every time. I do not know why. You know like highlighted. I do not know how to turn off that. (what happened with your skype and gtalk?)

Comment: @Johnny actually I added you on my Gtalk, its my mac not working so I cant get on skype yet